# Using Java Loops To Return To Another Portion of The Program?

Tags: java

I've been self-studying Java, and I'm stuck in regards to loops. I know that you can utilize 'while' loops to help bring a Java program back to a specific portion of the code... but I'm not sure how to implement.

Here's what I'm specifically looking for: upon the completion of either a valid or invalid result of my code, I would like it to return back to the portion of the code which prompts the user to enter a password.

Here's a copy of my code below... any assistance would be much appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  

      //Prompts the user to enter a password, and stores password in the string "passwordIn."
      System.out.print("Please enter a password to determine if it is valid or not: ");
      String passwordIn = input.nextLine();

      //Established various boolean checks to be passed in order for code to evaluate each character.
      boolean lengthCheck = false;
      boolean upperCheck = false;
      boolean lowerCheck = false;
      boolean digitCheck = false;
      boolean specialCheck = false;
      boolean check = false;

      //The loop will initiate the testing of the string.   
      for(int i = 0; i < passwordIn.length(); i++) {

      //Character pw represents the index!   
      char pw = passwordIn.charAt(i); 

      //This verifies that the password meets the length (at least 8 characters) requirement.
      if (passwordIn.length() >= 8) {
          lengthCheck = true;
          }   

     //This verifies that there is at least one uppercase letter in the password.
      if(Character.isUpperCase(pw)) {
           upperCheck = true;
           }
     //This verifies that there is at least one lowercase letter in the password.
      if(Character.isLowerCase(pw)) {
           lowerCheck = true;
           }
     //This verifies that there is at least one digit in the password. 
      if(Character.isDigit(pw)) {
           digitCheck = true;
           }

     //This verifies that there is at least one character that is not a letter or a number within the password.  
      if(!Character.isLetter(pw) && !Character.isDigit(pw)) {
           specialCheck = true;
           }
     }

      //Verifies the results of the loop to ensure that all checks are true.
      if(upperCheck == true && lowerCheck == true && digitCheck == true && lengthCheck == true && specialCheck == true) {
           check = true;
           }

      // Uses boolean to determine if password is valid.
      if (check == true) {
       System.out.print("\nThe password you entered was: " + passwordIn);
       System.out.print("\nVerdict: " + "\t" + "Valid");
       }
      else {
       System.out.print("\nThe password you entered was: " + passwordIn);
       System.out.print("\nVerdict: " + "\t" + "Invalid");

      }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, you normally test the boolean with a `while`

```
  boolean check = false;

  //The loop will initiate the testing of the string.   
  while(!check) {
```

However you will have to move the statement that reads in the password from the user for this to do anything useful.

```
  boolean check = false;

  //The loop will initiate the testing of the string.   
  while(!check) {

     //Prompts the user to enter a password, and stores password in the string "passwordIn."
     System.out.print("Please enter a password to determine if it is valid or not: ");
     String passwordIn = input.nextLine();

     // ... testing...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `do-while` loop for this as follows.

```
do{

  // logic to validate

} while(condition); // Your break condition here
```

This will **do** the logic once and then check for break condition. If it's `true` then it will perform the logic once again. This continues till break condition is encountered or the program terminates.